# sdf_bind_rows(a,b) %>% group_by(col1,col2) %>% sumarize(n=n()) crashes Spark and R

Tags: apache-spark, dplyr, sparklyr

Note: question 1st posted in [this sparklyr github issue](https://github.com/rstudio/sparklyr/issues/2111). Cross-posting to see if I have better luck here.

I sparklyr, I am trying to combine (rbind) two datasets and remove duplicates from the combined dataset. This has generated a series of errors, one of which I could reproduce in this example:

#### Reproducible Error code:

```
#install.packages("dplyr")
#install.packages("dbplyr")
#install.packages('sparklyr')

library(dplyr)
library(dbplyr)
library(sparklyr)
#spark_install(version = "2.1.0")

sc <- spark_connect(master = "local")

iris_tbl <- copy_to(sc, iris)
iris2 <- iris
iris_tbl2 <- copy_to(sc, iris2)
d <- sdf_bind_rows(iris_tbl,iris_tbl2) 
d %>% group_by(Sepal.Length,Sepal.Width) %>% summarize(dups=n())
```

This gives me the error below. 
All packages have been recently installed from their CRAN versions (see sessionInfo() output after the long error codes bellow. What can be happening???

In with my actual data, besides the error code, the command also crashes my R session, restarting Rstudio.

#### Error Message

````
Error: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve '```Sepal.Length```' given input columns: [Sepal_Length, Petal_Length, Petal_Width, Species, Sepal_Width]; line 3 pos 9;
'Aggregate ['`Sepal.Length`, '`Sepal.Width`], ['`Sepal.Length`, '`Sepal.Width`, count(1) AS dups#389L]
+- SubqueryAlias sparklyr_tmp_186015321ac5
+- Union
:- Project [Sepal_Length#21, Sepal_Width#22, Petal_Length#23, Petal_Width#24, Species#25]
:  +- SubqueryAlias sparklyr_tmp_18607e7315b6
:     +- Project [Sepal_Length#21, Sepal_Width#22, Petal_Length#23, Petal_Width#24, Species#25]
:        +- SubqueryAlias iris
:           +- LogicalRDD [Sepal_Length#21, Sepal_Width#22, Petal_Length#23, Petal_Width#24, Species#25]
+- Project [Sepal_Length#178, Sepal_Width#179, Petal_Length#180, Petal_Width#181, Species#182]
+- Project [Sepal_Length#178, Sepal_Width#179, Petal_Length#180, Petal_Width#181, Species#182]
+- SubqueryAlias sparklyr_tmp_18607b4484c
+- Project [Sepal_Length#178, Sepal_Width#179, Petal_Length#180, Petal_Width#181, Species#182]
+- SubqueryAlias iris2
+- LogicalRDD [Sepal_Length#178, Sepal_Width#179, Petal_Length#180, Petal_Width#181, Species#182]

at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.package$AnalysisErrorAt.failAnalysis(package.scala:42)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis$$anonfun$checkAnalysis$1$$anonfun$apply$2.applyOrElse(CheckAnalysis.scala:77)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis$$anonfun$checkAnalysis$1$$anonfun$apply$2.applyOrElse(CheckAnalysis.scala:74)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformUp$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:308)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformUp$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:308)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(TreeNode.scala:69)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformUp(TreeNode.scala:307)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan.transformExpressionUp$1(QueryPlan.scala:269)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$plans$QueryPlan$$recursiveTransform$2(QueryPlan.scala:279)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$plans$QueryPlan$$recursiveTransform$2$1.apply(QueryPlan.scala:283)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:234)
at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:104)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$plans$QueryPlan$$recursiveTransform$2(QueryPlan.scala:283)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan$$anonfun$8.apply(QueryPlan.scala:288)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapProductIterator(TreeNode.scala:186)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan.transformExpressionsUp(QueryPlan.scala:288)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis$$anonfun$checkAnalysis$1.apply(CheckAnalysis.scala:74)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis$$anonfun$checkAnalysis$1.apply(CheckAnalysis.scala:67)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.foreachUp(TreeNode.scala:126)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis$class.checkAnalysis(CheckAnalysis.scala:67)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer.checkAnalysis(Analyzer.scala:58)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.assertAnalyzed(QueryExecution.scala:49)
at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$.ofRows(Dataset.scala:64)
at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sql(SparkSession.scala:582)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor55.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at sparklyr.Invoke.invoke(invoke.scala:147)
at sparklyr.StreamHandler.handleMethodCall(stream.scala:123)
at sparklyr.StreamHandler.read(stream.scala:66)
at sparklyr.BackendHandler.channelRead0(handler.scala:51)
at sparklyr.BackendHandler.channelRead0(handler.scala:4)
at io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:105)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:308)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:294)
at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:103)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:308)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:294)
at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:244)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:308)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:294)
at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:846)
at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:131)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:511)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:468)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:382)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:354)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:111)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:137)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
````

#### Session Info

```
sessionInfo()
R version 3.4.2 (2017-09-28)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows Server >= 2012 x64 (build 9200)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Portuguese_Brazil.1252  LC_CTYPE=Portuguese_Brazil.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=Portuguese_Brazil.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                      
[5] LC_TIME=Portuguese_Brazil.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] sparklyr_1.0.2 dbplyr_1.4.2   dplyr_0.8.3   

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.2       rstudioapi_0.10  magrittr_1.5     tidyselect_0.2.5 R6_2.2.2        
 [6] rlang_0.4.0      httr_1.3.1       tools_3.4.2      parallel_3.4.2   config_0.3      
[11] DBI_1.0.0        withr_2.1.1      ellipsis_0.2.0.1 htmltools_0.3.6  openssl_1.0     
[16] yaml_2.1.16      assertthat_0.2.0 digest_0.6.15    rprojroot_1.3-2  tibble_2.1.3    
[21] forge_0.2.0      crayon_1.3.4     purrr_0.3.2      base64enc_0.1-3  htmlwidgets_1.3 
[26] glue_1.3.1       compiler_3.4.2   pillar_1.4.2     generics_0.0.2   backports_1.1.2 
[31] r2d3_0.2.3       jsonlite_1.5     pkgconfig_2.0.1
```

Answer (score 0):

The dots in column names get translated to `_` (instead of `.`), so this should work instead:

```
d %>% group_by(Sepal_Length, Sepal_Width) %>% summarize(dups=n())
```